# .htaccess don't blocks my files and folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to block a `composer.json` file and lib folder (e.g `example.com/lib` - 403, `example.com/lib/example.php` - displays file)

I tried:

```
<Files composer.json>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

And

```
<Files "composer.json">  
  Require all denied
</Files>
```

Comment: Is `AllowOverride` set up so that `.htaccess` files take effect?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller no, how i can setup it?

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html